# Using mongodb2 without mongoskin

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm

I'm using mongo and node.js to make a web app.I wrote a few .js files that use functions available in mongodb 2.0 (insertOne, insertMany etc) but every time I run npm start I get a notification that mongoskin needs a peer dependency and I need to install mongodb 1.4. I can't solve that problem so I was wondering if there is any way to get rid of mongoskin entirely. I still get this message when I write "npm uninstall mongoskin"

```
npm WARN mongoskin@1.4.13 requires a peer of mongodb@~1.4 but none was installed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem I was using monk 1.0.1 which depends on the existence of mongoskin 1.4 Upgrading to monk 2.0.0 solves the problem as the dependence does not exist in this version.